# installing angular/cli with unhandled problem

Tags: angular, npm

When I run the following command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> C:\Users\AA>npm install -g @angular/cli
> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
>
> @angular/cli@9.1.7 postinstall C:\Users\AA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
>
> + @angular/cli@9.1.7
> removed 1 package and updated 1 package in 15.551s
>
> C:\Users\AA>
> C:\Users\AA>ng --version
> An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\AA\node_modules'
> See "C:\Users\AA\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-MhKi22\angular-errors.log" for further details.
> ```

I have no idea, hope someone can help me out.

Comment: I have no idea, hope someone can help me out. I am using a proxy server because I have no one answer my question when I posted it in my country's website.

Comment: is this a brand new installation or are you upgrading a previous one?

Comment: first, I uninstall it and reinstall it.

Comment: While uninstalling it... did you remember to `npm cache verify`?

Answer (score 2):

Angular is looking for a 'node_modules' subfolder in the app. You have not created any app, but Angular it's looking for one nevertheless. Type:

> mkdir node_modules

And then execute again *ng v*

This error is a somewhat-well-document and recurrent error with angular-cli (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10523)). It's probably that you'll find additional errors when trying to run apps with *ng serve*. You'll probably have to install angular devkit with:

> npm install @angular-devkit/core --save-dev